# D3 how to remove tick dots from opaque scale

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have d3.scale.linear object. Using css I made that scale opaque:

```
.axis .domain {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.axis .halo {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-opacity: .5;
    stroke-width: 17px;
}
```

(example code taken from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6452972 )

---

[image]

---

as you can see, there are still some dots left from scale ticks.

I tried this css:

```
    .tick {
        opacity: 0;
    }
```

but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    .axis line {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

Solved the problem.

---

This is how it's done from javascript itself:

```
d3.select(".axis")
    .selectAll("line")
    .attr("style", "visibility: hidden;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the fill of the ticks to either transparent or the same color as your background color. Something like the following inside JS or using CSS.

```
.style {
   fill: transparent;
}
```

Hope this helps!